# Disable button if input date is lesser than 4 months

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

I want to disable the next button when the input date is lesser than 4 months. Get the current date and check if the current date is lesser than 4 months. If it's lesser disable the next button and give an alert.

I tried it with an alert button to test the datepicker, but that didn't work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#input_18_104').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var today = new Date();
      if ((new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 120)) < date) {
        //Do somthing here..
        alert(123);
      }

    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input name="input_104" id="input_18_104" type="text" class="datepicker medium mdy datepicker_no_icon hasDatepicker" tabindex="72" placeholder="Date?"> Next button:

<input type="button" id="next_button_18_94" class="form_next_button button" value="Next" tabindex="76">
```

Comment: Have you checked (e.g. with ``console.log``) that the ``onSelect`` function is triggered? Have you checked that your dates are the correct ones? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Using a ui-datepicker-calendar as datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual condition is wrong `today.getDate()+120` will give you a number higher than `120` which will lead to a wrong `date` then your comparison won't be always correct.

You need to compare the `month` values respectively, this is how you could do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input_18_104').datepicker()
        .on("input change", function (e) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var today = new Date();

            if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) > 4) {
                alert("The date is wrong");
            } else if (((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) == 4) && (today.getDate() > date.getDate())) {
                alert("The date is wrong");
            } else {
                console.log("Date is fine");
            }
        });
});
```

**Explanataion:**

- We used `date.getMonth() + 11` to make sure we don't get a negative
  value, so we added `11` to the 2 `months` values, so it won't affect
  the test.
- Then we check if the difference between these two values isn't higher than 4, so the choosen date is fine.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#input_18_104').datepicker()
        .on("input change", function(e) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var today = new Date();
            
            if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) > 4) {
              alert("The date is wrong");
            } else if (((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) == 4) && (today.getDate() > date.getDate())) {
                alert("The date is wrong");
              } else {
                console.log("Date is fine");
              }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input name="input_104" id="input_18_104" type="text" class="datepicker medium mdy datepicker_no_icon hasDatepicker" tabindex="72" placeholder="Date?"> Next button:

<input type="button" id="next_button_18_94" class="form_next_button button" value="Next" tabindex="76">
```

Comment: the `onselect` trigger does not work it does not enter the event the part you are saying comes later .

Comment: Actually browser will create the correct date - just try it yourself (testet in Firefox and Chrome): ``new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 120)`` will give something like ``Date 2018-02-27T23:00:00.000Z``

Comment: not working.. the date format is mm/dd/yyyy maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @can The way you were listening to the datepicker change was wrong, I updated the answer.

Comment: It's now detecting on months, is it possible to do this also with days?
Because it's now 11/08/2017 and when I choose for 07/07/2017 it doesn't give an alert..

Comment: @Can I edited the answer, to take into account the day difference as well :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @chsdk :)

Comment: @chsdk It doesn't work now, because it's now 2018 :)
It doesn't check the year.. 

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will work

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input_18_104").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
alert("Working");});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input name="input_104" id="input_18_104" type="text" class="datepicker medium mdy datepicker_no_icon hasDatepicker" tabindex="72" placeholder="Date?"> Next button:

<input type="button" id="next_button_18_94" class="form_next_button button" value="Next" tabindex="76">
```

Comment: How to detect if the current date is lesser than 4 months?

Answer (score 0):

Use **monthDiff** function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#input_18_104').datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var today = new Date();
            if (monthDiff(today, date) < 4) {
                //Do somthing here..
                alert(123);
            }

        },
    });
});

function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not too difficult.

`new Date` returns a timestamp in milliseconds. The date function  is pretty smart. You can overflow the months and days and it will correct it to the date: so a value of 14 as month will actually become February or March. But you really want to stay away from day calculation or subtracting months because of leap years, 30 and 31 day count etc. Comparing time stamps is safer.

```
new Date(date)
```

Just add 4 months:

```
//remember month is zero based, so correct with +1 to give correct date input.
future = new Date(today.getFullyear()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1+4)+"-"+today.getDate())
```

Now compare:

```
future < new Date(date);
```

When the selected date is bigger than the future 4 month date it will be more than 4 months.
Under the hood JavaScript compares timestamps which are counted in milliseconds from 1970-01-01 so whenever a timestamp is bigger than another it is in the future relative to the compared timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the dates based on their time values. That's not 100% accurate because not all months have 30 days, but ok. Here's a quick try

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#input_18_104').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
             var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
             var today = new Date();
             var threshold = 10368000000; // 120d in ms = 4*30*24*60*60*1000
             var d = today.getTime()-date.getTime();
             //console.log(d, d > threshold)
             
             // be optimistic...
             $('#next_button_18_94').attr('disabled', false);
             
             if (d < 0) {
                 // selected date is in the future => everything ok
                 return;
             }
             if (d > threshold) {
                 // oops, selected date more than 4 months in the past
                 $('#next_button_18_94').attr('disabled', true);
                 return;
             }
             
        },
    });
});
```

```css
#next_button_18_94[disabled]{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input name="input_104" id="input_18_104" type="text" tabindex="72" >
<input type="button" id="next_button_18_94" class="form_next_button button" value="Next" tabindex="76">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "lesser than 4 months" mean means the input date is less than 4 months before today, then a simple method is to add 4 months to the input date and see if it's less than today, then enable or disable the button as required, e.g.

```js
function checkDate(input) {
  var form = input.form;
  var now = new Date();
  var then = parseDate(input.value);
  addMonths(then, 4);
  form.actionButton.disabled = now > then;
}

function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/)
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]);
}

function addMonths(date, months) {
  var d = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + +months);
  if (date.getDate() != d) date.setDate(0);
  return date;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Date (yyyy-mm-dd)<input type="text" value="2017-01-01" name="date" onblur="checkDate(this)"><br>
  <input type="button" name="actionButton" onclick="console.log(this.form.date.value)" value="Do stuff" disabled>
```